# Time taken to give answer if probability is given.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is a question that I am struggling with:

*Since the password is periodically changed, you would like to know the answer as soon as possible. So you decide to interrogate the minions in an order which will take the least expected time (you can only use the machine on one minion at a time).
For example, you have captured two minions: minion A taking 10 minutes, and giving the answer with probability 1/2, and minion B taking 5 minutes, but giving the answer with probability 1/5.
If you interrogate A first, then you expect to take 12.5 minutes. If you interrogate B first, then you expect to take 13 minutes and thus must interrogate A first for the shortest expected time for getting the answer.*

I cannot figure out how the final time was calculated for each minion. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've seen this question on a google interview. There is one fact that was left out. The interrogation machine has a guaranteed setting but causes brain damage so it is only used on the last minion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minion $A$ first:

With probability $1/2$, $A$ will give the answer and you can stop: time taken is $10$.

With probability $1/2$, $A$ will not give the answer and you then ask $B$: time taken is $10+5=15$.

Expected time taken: $\dfrac{1}{2}\times 10 + \dfrac{1}{2}\times 15 = 12.5$.

$$\\$$

Minion $B$ first:

With probability $1/5$, $B$ will give the answer and you can stop: time taken is $5$.

With probability $4/5$, $B$ will not give the answer and you then ask $A$: time taken is $5+10=15$.

Expected time taken: $\dfrac{1}{5}\times 5 + \dfrac{4}{5}\times 15 = 13$.

Comment: why the second guy for sure will give the answer? Like if Minion A first and he didn't give answer, then you ask B, why B has to give the answer? Isn't B give answer with probability 1/5?

Comment: @KevinKim B doesn't have to give the answer. I don't assume you must have the answer at the end. We are only looking at the expected time taken.

Comment: Let T be the time when the true answer is given. In the case of Minion A first, then T can take value 10 with probability 1/2; 15 with probability 1/2 * 1/5; with probability 1/2*4/5, T can take value what? infinity? isn't it?

Comment: Hi @KevinKim . I interpret as follows: you can only ask each minion once, not repeatedly. Given that the OP seems to have quoted in his question the prescribed solution, I'm fairly sure this is the right interpretation.

Comment: That's exactly the place I feel confused. I agree with you that we can ask each minion once, which results in a positive probability that after you asked both of them, you get no answer. Then in this case, the time to get true answer is undefined.